# ASP Page performance is poor and differs greatly across environments

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Firstly apologies I cannot be more specific as if I could then I might know where to look. I have an ASP.net web app with a bunch of pages using AjaxControlToolKit. The speed the pages render differs greatly between my two environments. On one it is super slow taking a `~5 seconds` to render a relatively simple page which has two grids and a bunch of controls. Everywhere i look articles say "check your SQL" but that cannot be it as SQL perf should be common across all environments. I have also narrowed it down to where the page is just doing a basic post back, no sql, and still the issue is repro. A user clicks Select All and we check a bunch of items in a list. I timed the code behind for this and it is fast `00:00:00.0002178`.

The two environments are sitting side by side, same location, both have IE9, except one is running on W2K8 and one is W7. That is the only real difference. On W7 the pages are *relatively* fast to render.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Changing the debug to false did have a positive impact.

Debug   Page Time
True    0.143363802770544
False   0.0377570798614921

So what I will do next is systematically look at each component of the application to see why I am making mistakes, SQL, ViewState, etc. I'll update the post with my final findings for those interested.

Thanks All for the help!

Comment: Should this be tagged WebForms instead of MVC?

Comment: WebForms since he is using AjaxControlToolkit

Comment: can you give us the url to check it out ?

Comment: @Aristos unfortunately not, since I have not set it up as external yet :(

Comment: check if you have any huge viewstate.

Comment: @Aristos yes I have my suspisions that might be it. Currently reading the following article http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following

1. Check the CPU usage on the server through task manager (web app and database). Is it maxed out
2. Are the servers out of physical memory - again task manager
3. Are the returned pages massive. This is obvious but sometimes it's not. Sheer quantity of HTML can kill a page dead. This could be hidden (ViewState, elements with display:'none') or actually on the page but you are so used to looking that you can't see
4. Get fiddler onto it. Are you calling any external resources you shouldn't be. maybe there is a web service you are relying on that is suddenly inaccessible from a particular box. We had a twitter feed that was timing out that totally killed a site.
5. Do profile the database. You think it can't be but are you sure. Are you sure you're sure. You might not be comparing like with like and bring back huge amounts of data on one test without realising.
6. Certain processes are very sensitive to page/data length. For instance I had a regex that utterly failed and timed the page out once the page reached a certain size. The performance hardly tailed off - it stopped dead (badly written - who did that - erm me!!)
7. Is the physical box just dying. Are they any other processes/sites on there that are killing it. Who are you sharing the box with? Is the hard disc on it's way out?
8. Firewalls can be naughty. We have seen massive increases in performance by rebooting a physical firewall. Can you trace those packets?

Any there will be more - performance debugging can be a bit of an art. But hey - we're all artists aren't we.

Answer (score 0):

I probably first check to see whether I have 'debug' mode switched on in my web.config

Comment: Yes debug=true in the build. Let me read up on the impact of this and see if it makes a difference though I would have expected the perf impact of debug-true to be the same across all servers.